# Swift Optional Template Type unexpected parameter behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a converter class where T could be an optional type.

```
class Converter<T>
{
    init(){}

    func convertVal(_ val: T) -> T
    {
        print("val: \(val)")
        print(type(of: val))
        print("val is nil:  \(val == nil)")
        return val
    }
}

let firstStr: String? = nil

let converter = Converter<String?>()



var str = converter.convertVal(firstStr)
```

When i'am trying to convert a nil value:

Is printing :

```
val: nil
Optional<String>
val is nil:  false
```

Why is printing `nil` and the condition `val == nil` is `false`?

Comment: In your example, the `nil` in `val == nil` is being inferred to mean `Optional<Optional<String>>.none`. And val is `Optional<String>.some(Optional<String>.none)`, which isn't equal.

Comment: @Alexander How can be unwrap safely to test if nil or make it usable? I also tried to put ! ( the unwrapper ) after it but doesn't work, it will still be Optional<Optional<String>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is make `convertVal` function's parameter and return type optional and the `Converter`s type a regular `String` instead.

```
class Converter<T> {
    init() {}

    func convertVal(_ val: T?) -> T? {
        print("val: \(val)")
        print(type(of: val))
        print("val is nil: \(val == nil)")
        return val
    }
}

let firstStr: String? = nil

let converter = Converter<String>()
var str = converter.convertVal(firstStr)
```

Output:

```
val: nil
Optional<String>
val is nil: true
```

Comment: I want to have some converters that can or can't have optional values. In your example convertVal will always return a optional value, something that i want control with the T type.

Comment: @4bottiglie You don't control optionality with a generic type, I believe.  If you want this convertVal to only return non-optional T, then do so:  func convertVal(_ val: T?) -> T.  Basically, I don't think the generic type encapsulates optionality.

Comment: I basically needed a class that have the same Type as parameter and return type. convertVal(_ val: T?) -> T? or convertVal(_ val: T) -> T. As i can see swift doesn't support optional type as template because it produces unexpected behaviours.